# how to get the indices of specific set of rows

Tags: python, naivebayes

```
feature_log_prob_sorted = np.abs(naive.feature_log_prob_).argsort()

feature_log_prob_sorted = feature_log_prob_sorted[ : : -1]
```

Here naive is BernoulliNB's object and `feature_log_prob_` is empirical log probability of features given a class.

After applying the NB model on certain data I was trying to get the top 20 probabilities.

`argsort()` function return the indices of values from low probability to high probability so I have inverted the data.

Now I want to know the indices of top 20 value. How can I get it?

Comment: `feature_log_prob_sorted[:20]`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the top `n` values of a sorted list, use:

```
top_n = feature_log_prob_sorted[:n]
```

Comment: i don't want top value i want the index of those values. feature_log_prob_  will give an array. Now when i rearrange (i.e sorted) i will get top probabilities.  i want index value for those top values